# Laravel email with bootstrap styles

Tags: laravel

I use the following code to send email:

```
Mail::to('someemail@gmail.com')->send(new SampleMailTemplate());
```

In SampleMailTemplate I have the following:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.sampleTest');
}
```

In emails/sampleTest.blade.php I have:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <style>//boostrap.min.css goes here</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                <img src="{{asset('/uploads/emails/header.png')}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I send the email to any gmail email, It is showing without styles.
I read that some email clients does not support link or style tags.
So anyone has a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Only inline CSS styles work in case of HTML in emails.

Comment: even some css rules are not respected by Chrome. e.g. absolute position with top and left.

Answer (score 0):

Using inline css in your emails is the best option.

Also, from my experience, it is more stable to build emails with  tags than with divs.

In case you want to use bootrap, you might want to check [bootstrapemail](https://bootstrapemail.com/)